# Create an ANTLR grammar rule that returns function name as a token if it finds a doctype comment above the function declaration

Tags: java, coldfusion, antlr, coldfusion-10

This is the code sample which I want to parse. I want `getSaveable PaymentMethodsSmartList()` as a token, when I overwrite the function in the parserBaseListener.java file created by ANTLR.

```
 /** @suppress */
 public any function getSaveablePaymentMethodsSmartList() {
    if(!structKeyExists(variables, "saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList")) {
        variables.saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList = getService("paymentService").getPaymentMethodSmartList();
        variables.saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList.addFilter('activeFlag', 1);
        variables.saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList.addFilter('allowSaveFlag', 1);
        variables.saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList.addInFilter('paymentMethodType', 'creditCard,giftCard,external,termPayment');
        if(len(setting('accountEligiblePaymentMethods'))) {
            variables.saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList.addInFilter('paymentMethodID', setting('accountEligiblePaymentMethods'));
        }
    }
    return variables.saveablePaymentMethodsSmartList;
}
```

I already have the grammar that parses function declaration, but I need a new rule that can associate doctype comments with a function declaration and give the function name as separate token if there is a doctype comment associated with it.

Grammar looks like this:

```
functionDeclaration
  : accessType? typeSpec? FUNCTION identifier 
    LEFTPAREN parameterList? RIGHTPAREN
    functionAttribute* body=compoundStatement

  ;
```

Comment: Beacuse I want to show the code I am parsing. Can you help me with the grammer?

Comment: To Ira's point, `public any function` is not ColdFusion

Comment: @JamesAMohler - That *is* a CF function (in cfscript) ;-). Granted, it does sound like the question is ultimately about java syntax.

Comment: thank you Ira for your answer. This is cold fusion in cfscript. This is just a small part of the cfc file I am trying to parse.

Comment: @Leigh: I just confirmed that the syntax works on CF 2016

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Though I could have sworn that syntax was introduced in CF10, [looks like the whole `public|private type function...` syntax was supported back in CF9 too.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSE99A664D-44E3-44d1-92A0-5FDF8D82B55C.html).

Comment: Ira tags and script both exist...:)

Answer (score 2):

You want grammar rules that:

- return X if something "far away" in the source is a A,
- returns Y if something far away is a B (or ...).

In general, this is *context dependency*.  It is not handled well by  *context free grammars*, which is something that ANTLR is trying to approximate with its BNF rules.  In essence, what you think you want to do is to encode history of what the parser has seen long ago, to influence what is being produced now.  Generally that is hard.

The usual solution to something like this is to not address it in the grammar at all.   Instead:

- have the grammar rules produce an X regardless of what is far away,
- build a tree as  you parse (ANTLR does this for you); this captures not only X but everything about the parsed entity, including tokens for A that are far away
- walk over the tree,  interpreting a found X as Y if the tree contains the A  (usually far away in the tree).

For  your specific case of docstring-influences-function name, you can probably get away with encoding far away history.

You need (IMHO, ugly) grammar rules that look something like this:

```
 functionDeclaration: documented_function | undocumented_function ;

 documented_function: docstring accessType? typeSpec? FUNCTION
       documented_function_identifier rest_of_function ;

 undocumented_function: accessType? typeSpec? FUNCTION
       identifier rest_of_function ;

 rest_of_function: // avoids duplication, not pretty 
       LEFTPAREN parameterList? RIGHTPAREN
       functionAttribute* body=compoundStatement ;
```

You have to recognize the docstring as an explicit token that can be "seen" by the parser, which means modifying your lexer to make docstrings from comments (e.g, whitespace) into tokens.   [This is the first ugly thing].   Then having seen such a docstring, the lexer has to switch to a lexical mode that will pick up identifier-like text and produce **documented_function_identifier**, and then switch back to normal mode.   [This is the second ugly thing].  What you are doing is implementing literally a context dependency.

The reason you can accomplish this in spite of my remarks about context dependency is that A is not very far away; it is within few tokens of X.

So, you *could* do it this way.  I would not do this; you are trying to make the parser do too much.  Stick to the "usual solution".  (You'll have different problem: your A is a comment/whitespace, and probably isn't stored in the tree by ANTLR.  You'll have to solve that; I'm not an ANTLR expert.)